# HTTP requests are not distinguished

Tags: firebase, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am now making firebase custom token using **aws Lambda** and aws **API Gateway** and **Golang**

There is a problem here. case "GET": does not work to distinguish HTTP requests using a switch.

Here is my code

```
package main

import (
"os"

"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
)

func main() {
   region := os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")

   _, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
       Region: aws.String(region),
   })
   if err != nil {
       return
   }

   lambda.Start(handler)
}

func handler(req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) 
   (*events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
   switch req.HTTPMethod {
   case "GET":
       return handlers.GetToken(req)
   default:
       return handlers.UnhandleMethod()
   } 
}
```

if i send GET request to my lambda function using postman like this

> https://4abcabcabc.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/staging?phoneNum=1&password=1

All my HTTP GET requests are being defaulted.

I've already done GOOS=linux, GOARCH=amd64

now I'm using postman to test

Any help would be very very appreciate

Comment: what is the output for `fmt.Println(req.HTTPMethod)`? Put that before the switch statement and add the result to your question

Comment: @AliPadida Thanks alot! output is empty string "",  The req itself is not initialized. Is there anything I need to check?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API you're using, maybe you should add more of your code. The parts related to the caller of `handler` function and maybe before that.